# Passing a function to another function as statement

Tags: scala, functional-programming, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I want to write a function which will return true if given an even number as an argument or false otherwise. additionally, write a function that will filter a list of numbers returning just the even numbers. All done using Scala functional programming. This is what I have:

```
def isEven(n:Int): Boolean = n % 2 == 0
    println(isEven(4))

val filterEven  =  ( xs :List[Int] )  => {
    for(  x <- xs;   if x % 2 == 0  )  yield x
}
println(filterEven(List(3,2,4,5,6,22,91)))
```

My question is, how can I pass the first function "isEven" to to the "filterEven" function in order to replace the "if-statement"?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass isEven as a parameter to `xs.filter`

`def filterEven(xs: List[Int]) = xs.filter(isEven)`

This is functionally equivalent to:

`def filterEven(xs: List[Int]) = for { x <- xs if isEven(x) } yield x`

Answer (score 1):

First you give it a name when it is passed in.

```
val filterEven = (xs :List[Int], filterFunc: Int => Boolean)  => {
```

Then you invoke it under its new name.

```
  for(x <- xs; if filterFunc(x)) yield x
```

Note that now `filterEven` is not a good name for your function. The parameter passed in as `filterFunc` will determine whether you filter even, or odd, or less than 100, or .....